# Need to convert a date range to multiple date entry in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which will get inserted for a particular date range.

```
INSERT INTO task (Task,Description,startdate,enddate) VALUES ('$Task', '$Description', '$start_date', '$end_date', );
```

But I need to create multiple date entry as per the startdate and end date. For example i selected 01-02-2014 as start date and 10-02-2014 as end date. it should create 10 multiple entry each one for each date starting from 01 till 10.

Please help how to solve this

Comment: I don't know a shortcut one sql query answer, but you can create multiple [bulk insert syntax] query created using iterating on date range.

Answer (score 0):

To conserve entries maybe you should instead
     SELECT
anything that falls inbetween in the data processing stage instead?

Otherwise the easiest solution would be to loop through days and insert in PHP rather than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$dStart = new DateTime('01-02-2014');
   $dEnd  = new DateTime('10-02-2014');
   $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
   for($i =1; $i<=$dDiff->d; $i++) {
    //increase your date here
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO task (Task,Description,startdate,enddate) VALUES ('$Task', '$Description', '$start_date', '$end_date'");

   }
```

Comment: But the dates i am not giving like that, its taking from the input field. So hwhat to do

Comment: must be 01-02-2014 looks like it however m-d-y or d-m-y,y-m-d

Comment: <b>From Date:&nbsp;</b> <input type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate"readonly />
     
<b>To Date:&nbsp;</b><input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate"  readonly />

The date will be input from these two fields. As per the input dates, I need to create multiple entries